# Webview settings

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I just want to check let's say if I do this in my app (For the web view)
Will it affect other application's too? I mean if I set the web view  settings will it affected as global web view setting?

```
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Comment: no, its doesn't affect any other webview.

Comment: No you cannot change the global setting

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel    The strange thing my web view didn't work on Oreo but after I enabled this it worked then I uninstall  the app  and checked  again without this settings it worked I am wondering how was that  even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [doc for WebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html):

> Manages settings state for a WebView. When a WebView is first created, it obtains a set of default settings. These default settings will be returned from any getter call. A WebSettings object obtained from WebView.getSettings() is tied to the life of the WebView. If a WebView has been destroyed, any method call on WebSettings will throw an IllegalStateException.

So in short: No, it won't affect global settings for WebView (as there are no global settings).

Comment: On Oreo web view din't load  but after I enabling above code  it worked then I uninstall the app and checked again without these  settings it worked do you have any idea how is that even possible ?